# How to simplify or reduce the code in C#?

Tags: c#

i'm developing a windows form application in C#, i'm new in this haha.
So, i have this code, it works good, but it's a lot of code :/, and i want to simplyfy or reduce that...
This is my code, is about comparations of hours, ex:

Start date: 20:30

End date: 21:00

Date time now: 20:33.

So the result gonna be true, but i need to do a lot of comparations, and i have a lot of ifs, how can i reduce it?...

```
public int verifyHour()
        {
            string hourMinute = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
            bool h1 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(20, 25, 0), new TimeSpan(20, 30, 0));
            if(h1 == true)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            bool h2 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(8, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(9, 00, 0));
            if (h2 == true)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            bool h3 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(9, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(10, 00, 0));
            if (h3 == true)
            {
                return 3;
            }

            bool h4 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(11, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 00, 0));
            if (h4 == true)
            {
                return 4;
            }

            bool h5 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(12, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(13, 00, 0));
            if (h5 == true)
            {
                return 5;
            }
            bool h6 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(13, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(14, 00, 0));
            if (h6 == true)
            {
                return 6;
            }
            bool h7 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(14, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(15, 00, 0));
            if (h7 == true)
            {
                return 7;
            }
            bool h8 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(15, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(16, 00, 0));
            if (h8 == true)
            {
                return 8;
            }
            bool h9 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(16, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 0));
            if (h9 == true)
            {
                return 9;
            }
            bool h10 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(16, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 0));
            if (h10 == true)
            {
                return 10;
            }
            bool h11 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(17, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(18, 00, 0));
            if (h11 == true)
            {
                return 11;
            }
            bool h12 = IsTimeOfDayBetween(Convert.ToDateTime(hourMinute), new TimeSpan(18, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 00, 0));
            if (h12 == true)
            {
                return 12;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I recommend you to post this question to codereview.stackexchange.com since Stack Overflow is not a platform for reviews.

Comment: i think switch-case will be a better choice.

Comment: Hmm, i also think in switch-case, but i don't know how can i implement this, because i need to compare the actual hour and minute, with start hour-minute time, and end hour-minute time...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on codereview, not on SO.

Comment: Whenever you have lots of copy and paste code, it is time to create arrays.

Comment: Is all your are doing is checking if `now` is between `start` and `end`?

Comment: Hint: Find the logic between the return value and the `TimeSpan()` values.

Comment: "it works good" I don't think so .. it will never return 10

Comment: Don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplification of what you wrote, although it may be wrong, because your h4 does not check from 10:00 ~ 11:00 (and go on) and you have double check on 16:00 ~ 17:00, that makes that you can never return 10.

```
public int verifyHour(DateTime datetime)
{
   if(datetime.Hour == 20 && datetime.Minute >= 25 && datetime.Minute <= 30)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   else(datetime.Hour <= 8 && datetime.Hour <= 18)
   {
       return datetime.Hour - 6;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

If you want to verify from string

```
public int VerifyHour(string hourminute)
{
    DateTime datetime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(hourminute, out datetime))
    {
        int result = datetime.Hour;
        if(datetime.Hour == 20 && datetime.Minute >= 25 && datetime.Minute <= 30)
        {
             return 1;
        }
        else(datetime.Hour <= 8 && datetime.Hour <= 18)
        {
             return datetime.Hour - 6;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure who and why downvoted the answer, but this is VERY elegant reuse of the standard library!

Comment: So how does this answer _"and i have a lot of ifs, how can i reduce it?..."_?  All I see is a helper function for returning the _hour_

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Wrapping a single method call to `DataTime` and returning a property is hardly _"elegant"_

Comment: @MickyD of course it is! I don't want to rewrite one's new implementation of a bicycle!

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko _"bicycle"_?  Try wing-nut

Comment: @mickyD the code provided by kurakura88 is the equivalent. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If the original question is about how to determine if a certain time is in between 2 times, then this how you should code:

```
public bool IsInBetween(DateTime target, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return start <= target && target <= end;
}
```

again if it is from string:

```
public bool IsInBetween(string target, string start, string end)
{
    DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Parse(target);
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(start);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(end);

    return startDate <= targetDate && targetDate <= endDate;
}
```

Comment: Again, how does this address _"but i need to do a lot of comparations, and i have a lot of ifs, how can i reduce it?..."_.  OP already has a `IsTimeOfDayBetween` and you've just renamed it.  The question is about **how to simpify the calling code**, not `IsTimeOfDayBetween` or `IsInBetween`

Comment: to be honest I am not clear on what the OP is asking and second thing I also do not really know what you are looking for either. I am just throwing answers that may help to OP. So here, OP has `startdate`, `enddate`, and he wanted to verify if the `DateTime.now` is in between, then the result is true. Therefore, here it is. If the question is about just reducing the amount of comparisons, then my previous answer is, use the available library. The name difference is because the parameter is different, we should not take `TimeSpan` as input, because that class is for different purpose.

Comment: Feel free to flag it or -1 if it is totally wrong or off topic.

Answer (score 0):

A (oversimplified) suggestion would be:

If you are comparing just the hours to the second, just do:

```
public static int GetSeconds(DateTime dateTime) {
    return (dateTime.Hour * 3600) + (dateTime.Minutes * 60) + dateTime.Seconds;
}

public bool IsBetween(DateTime target, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    var targetSeconds = GetSeconds(target);
    var startSeconds = GetSeconds(start);
    var endSeconds = GetSeconds(end);

    return startSeconds <= targetSeconds && endSeconds >= targetSeconds;
}
```

If you are comparing just the hours to the minute, just do:

```
public static int GetMinutes(DateTime dateTime) {
    return (dateTime.Hour * 60) + dateTime.Minutes
}

public bool IsBetween(DateTime target, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    var targetMinutes = GetMinutes(target);
    var startMinutes = GetMinutes(start);
    var endMinutes = GetMinutes(end);

    return startMinutes <= targetMinutes && endMinutes >= targetMinutes ;
}
```

Comment: But, i need to compare if the actual hour and minute, Is in a certain range, for example, if 20:30, is in range of 20:20 and 20:40..

Comment: ok, you need to change your question, then... You didn't specify that. You junst mentioned that you return "true"

Comment: so, you actually want to know what range you are?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to return different values than the current time because you are setting 8AM to 2. In programming the situation you seem to have arived on is a [switch statement](https://www.dotnetperls.com/switch). So you would set up your code like this using a switch statement.

```
public int verifyHour()
{
    int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
    switch(hour) 
    {
        case 8:
            return 1;
            break; // not really necessary because you are returning but you should put these in for practice
       case 9:
            return 2;
            break;
       ... // so on for the rest of your cases
       default:  
            return -1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Once you get there you can probably clean it up further by thinking about what input you are taking and what are you returning and simply doing math on the return statement to alter the current time to the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on exactly what the purpose of the OP function is, but you can reduce it quite a bit if you use a loop for the middle part.  Note that I've written this function to return exactly what the OP function returns:

```
public int verifyHour()
{
    Datetime nowConverted = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(nowConverted, new TimeSpan(20, 25, 0), new TimeSpan(20, 30, 0)))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 2, time = 8; i <= 12; ++i, ++time)
    {
        if (IsTimeOfDayBetween(nowConverted, new TimeSpan(time, 00, 0), new TimeSpan(time + 1, 00, 0))
        {
            return i;
        }
        else if (time == 9) //You don't compare between 10 and 11
        {
            ++time;
        }
        else if (time == 16) //You repeat this twice, so 10 will never be returned
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```